# Do not resolve Unicode entities when converting from Typescript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode

I'm the new to TypeScript, I have a string like that in typescript:

```
class X {private static str = '[\u2639\u263a\u263b]';}
```

when I build this file to javascript, this string will become:

```
X.str = '[☹☺☻]'
```

I know both are the same. But in my requirement, I want to keep it as original format, like that:

```
X.str = '[\u2639\u263a\u263b]';
```

Is there any way to make the compiler doesn't convert unicode in csproj file?

Comment: `string str = 'my str';` is invalid syntax

Comment: Yes, just for example. I will modify it. Thanks:)

Comment: That doesn't happen locally or in the playground. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7Bprivate%20static%20str%20%3D%20'%5B%5Cu2639%5Cu263a%5Cu263b%5D'%3B%7D

Comment: I see. But in my case, it will convert like that. so is there any way to force it keep original string in csproj?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in my case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see. But in my case, it will convert like that. so is there any way to force it keep original string in csproj?

Comment: why this will convert in your case? I did not not get your point.